# Можно ли сделать вставку мобильного сайта в приложение

Tags: ios, мобильные-приложения

Есть мобильная версия сайта. Нужно сделать приложения для ios.

Приложение должно быть полностью идентичным мобильному сайту, так что смысла делать приложение с нуля не вижу. Можно ли сделать вставку мобильного сайта в приложение, как это можно реализовать ?

Comment: Да, есть, пользоваться мобильным браузером и сделать верстку адаптивной под мобильные экраны, если таковой еще нет.

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Это абсолютно разные вещи! И или пилить (а если еще "полностью идентичным мобильному сайту" - очень пилить) новое приложение или же "читайте выше"

Comment: да все можно. сделайте UIWebView и в нем показывайте свой сайт

Comment: 1. Вопрос про iOS, но в тегах почему-то android. 2. Это сделать можно, но этого делать не за чем, т. к. есть мобильный сайт.

Answer (score 3):

Сделать можно, если:

- сайт сверстан на "чистом" html, т.е. нет серверной генерации кода: asp.net, php
- запросы к серверу идут через ajax

Если вышеуказанные пункты выполняются, то смело можно использовать [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/guide/overview/), хотя код всё равно придется немного переписывать.

Сам я уже давно использую эту технологию и считаю, что лучше для мобильника всегда писать отдельное приложение (уйдет намного меньше времени), с отдельным дизайном (хотя можно использовать стиль самого сайта). Сделать такие приложения можно с помощью [Sencha](https://www.sencha.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Некоторые приложения просто отображают сайт в UIWebView. Если сайт с адаптивной версткой, то можно сделать именно так. 
Но, конечно же, на свой страх и риск.

Answer (score 0):

Сделать все можно, другой вопрос уговорить apple это принять в аппстор. В частности вот что они там пишут

> 4.2 Minimum Functionality
>
> Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it beyond a repackaged website. If your app is not particularly useful, unique, or “app-like,” it doesn’t belong on the App Store. If your App doesn't provide some sort of lasting entertainment value, or is just plain creepy, it may not be accepted. Apps that are simply a song or movie should be submitted to the iTunes store. Apps that are simply a book or game guide should be submitted to the iBooks Store.